# is there any boilerplates for a reactjs and react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, boilerplate

we are starting a new webapp using reactjs, the main reason why we chose react is because of react-native !, the app will be password protected, so we are not going to utilize and seo or server rendering features.

i find most boilerplates for react focus on universal setup yet in my case i want to structure app to sharing most amount of code possible between web and mobile apps

we started our webapp using https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate

is there a production ready boilerplate/starter that can be used in such use case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're still a bit premature to try to share a lot of code between React and React Native. Ben Alpert, one of the React core team members at Facebook, said this in a [recent AMA](https://hashnode.com/ama/with-ben-alpert-cis53jvri0201hq53dm93l4e1):

> Over time, maybe we can share view code between native and web too. There are some cool projects in the community like react-native-web (https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) which try to make this possible. We don't have anything to show at Facebook yet down this road but maybe **in a year or two** we could officially support using View, Image, and Text on the web for people who want to.

*(emphasis mine)*

For React Native, I would recommend taking a look at [Ignite](https://infinite.red/ignite) by Infinite Red (disclaimer: I'm one of the owners of Infinite Red). It gives you a great starting point and provides a lot of tools (including the fantastic [Reactotron](https://github.com/reactotron/reactotron)) to get you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

[Create React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#creating-a-new-application) is the best way to start building a new React single page application. It sets up your development environment so that you can use the latest JavaScript features, provides a nice developer experience, and optimizes your app for production.

[Create React Native App](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#getting-started) is the easiest way to start building a new React Native application. It allows you to start a project without installing or configuring any tools to build native code - no Xcode or Android Studio installation required.